# Is it "au-delà de la simplicité" or "au-delà la simplicité"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

> [l’idée d’une Église pauvre va bien au-delà de la simplicité matérielle](http://www.la-croix.com/Religion/Actualite/L-Eglise-que-veut-le-pape-Francois-2013-07-30-992764)

In this [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/au-del%C3%A0_1?showCookiePolicy=true), *au-delà* (spelt, however, *au delà*) means only *beyond*.

If *au-delà* (or *au delà*) means *beyond*, why was *simplicité* used after it in the genitive?

Shouldn't there have been *au-delà **la** simplicité matérielle*: *beyond **the** simplicity of things*?

Comment: Interesting orthographic tendencies… http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=au-del%C3%A0+les%2Cau-del%C3%A0+des%2Cau+del%C3%A0+les%2Cau+del%C3%A0+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19

Answer (score 3):

*Au-delà* can be used in two ways, as a location adverb.

- *au-delà de* when the location is specified

  > Il est interdit d'aller au-delà de la barrière *(It's forbidden to go beyond the fence)*
- *au-delà* when the location is already known, and doesn't have to be specified

  > Tu peux aller jusqu'à la barrière, mais c'est interdit au-delà. (*You can go as far as the fence, but it's forgotten to go beyond.*)

So in your example, the correct form is indeed *au-delà de la simplicité matérielle*.

See more examples in the [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au-del%C3%A0).

Comment: So in my example, it's _au-delà de_: specified location. Now it's all clear.

Comment: Sorry, I spent some time on examples, and in the end I forgot to answer the actual question :)
Answer edited.